# Everyplay ios sdk build has expired alert

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, everyplay

I am seeing "Build has expired, please upgrade" alert on my iphone Unity3d game with everyplay.
I am using the latest plugin from Unity Asset Store - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16005.

Does everyplay team need to upgrade unity-sdk ? Where do I download latest unity-everyplay-sdk?

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same.  Opened issue on github.  https://github.com/Everyplay/everyplay-ios-sdk/issues/21